# jclouds IOExpection: Error writing request body to server

Tags: java, jclouds, cloudfiles, rackspace-cloudfiles

We are using `jclouds` with `Rackspace` and when uploading lots of files via `cloudfile api` (`multi threaded`)

Once in while we are getting an exception on `objectApi.put` line (see example code at bottom)

### Exception

```
16-Jul-2015 11:58:00.811 SEVERE [threadsPool-1]      org.jclouds.logging.jdk.JDKLogger.logError error after writing 8192/streaming bytes to https://*****/****.jpg
 java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3478)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3461)
        at com.google.common.io.CountingOutputStream.write(CountingOutputStream.java:53)
        at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:74)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.writePayloadToConnection(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:297)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:160)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:64)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:91)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:90)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:73)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:44)
        at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
        at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy176.put(Unknown Source)
        at
```

### Similar issue with `S3`

[can be found here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jclouds-dev/201504.mbox/%3CCAHtp1K2vRaZxQCBAR8ZCjXoXxbnz58hNZCtFmmrNjYKSJ7dHgw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

### Example Code

```
ObjectApi objectApi = cloudFiles.getObjectApi(REGION, container);
ByteSource byteSource = Files.asByteSource(file);
Payload payload = Payloads.newByteSourcePayload(byteSource);
objectApi.put(hashedName, payload);
```

### The question:

Any one has experience some behavior like that? maybe someone has workaround for that kind of issue?

Thanks

Alon

Answer (score 1):

Networks are unreliable, so expect some exceptions when using cloud services, especially when dealing with many files. Specifically for jclouds uploads, we have some example code here:

https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/blobstore-uploader

Edit: I have also added a JIRA issue to make sure we add a test specifically for this situation in swift:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-965

Comment: jclouds retry mechanism should handle network errors for repeatable payloads, e.g., ByteSource.  Users need not add their own retry logic unless they use InputStream payloads.

Comment: I am investigating potentially missing retry logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For now the retry logic does not work, so we warp it with a loop and try/catch in order to force the retry.